# Start Activity For Result - From View Model Class in MVVM Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, gallery, startactivityforresult

I have created MVVM architecture for my project, Now I am trying to open Gallery and Camera for images from View Model class, I am not able to call 'startActivityForResult' method from view model class, Someone please help.. ..

Comment: I think it's not the presentation layer who calls logics related to android contexts. How about calling it from the activtiy via a callback?

Comment: And by the way, just a context does not have startActivityForResult. Children of Fragments or Activities has it.

Comment: You can't. Even if you use `AndroidViewModel` component, `startActivityForResult` is only for Activities & Fragments. Why aren't you starting the activity from fragment/activity though?

Comment: @March3April4 Definitely March Context doesn't have startActivityForResult. This was problem I was facing with.

Comment: @DarShan I can't call it from Fragment Or Activity because I have ViewModel for it.

Comment: I have tried passing activity through Constructor and and using it in ViewModel, Someone Please confirm, whether there is any better alternative.. ..

Comment: Post relevant code so we can take a look & suggest on that.